# Java.util.timer timer null pointer exception

Tags: java, tomcat, timer, nullpointerexception

I'm using Apache Tomcate 7.0.39, Eclipse Java EE Juno, Java JRE 7 & Java JDK 1.7.0_13.

I have a problem with my timer. I have two functions, the first one starts the timer and perform a task, the other one stops the timer.
But the timer never stops because it is null.

My Java code :

```
public class TestXMLSQLTimerLocal
{
    public Timer timer;

    public TestXMLSQLTimerLocal()
    {

    }

    public void start()
    {
        this.timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask task = new TimerTask()
        {
            public void run()
            {
            //Some code
            }
        };

        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 60000);
    }
    public void stop() {
        this.timer.cancel();
    }
}
```

My JSP Page :

```
<%@page import="com.accenture.api.TestXMLSQLTimerLocal" %>
<%@page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%
String text = "Press the Start button to begin !";
String action = request.getParameter("action");
TestXMLSQLTimerLocal TM = new TestXMLSQLTimerLocal();
if ("Start".equals(action))
{
    TM.start();
    text = "The data are being transferred. Press the Stop button when you want to stop the transfer !";
}
if("Stop".equals(action))
{
    TM.stop();
    text = "The transfer is stopped. Press the Start button to begin the transfer again !";
}
%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Transfer Module</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="StartTM" action="#">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="Start"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Start"/>
    </form>
    <br />
    <p><%=text%></p>
    <br />
    <form name="StopTM" action="#">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="Stop"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Stop"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The start() and stop() are called by a Start and a Stop button on a simple JSP page.

For me, the issue is that the timer is still null because the modification in the Start() method are not taking in account.
Someone can help me?
If you need more information, please ask me

Comment: Are you sure that the start() is called before stop() ? Put some debug statements.

Comment: Yes, and nothing appears in the log files of Tomcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your calling this from a JSP, the instance of `TestXMLSQLTimerLocal` that spawned the new thread as well as the `Timer` are not available when a user presses the stop button.

You need to add an instance of `TestXMLSQLTimerLocal` to the session, or more preferably the applicationContext.  When you perform operations against this instance always pull it from session.

To add an instance of `TestXMLSQLTimerLocal` to session:

```
//From Servlet
request.getSession().addAttribute("timer", new TestXMLSQLTimerLocal());
```

To add the instance to Application Scope you would need to use, a [ServletContextListener](http://www.javabeat.net/2009/02/servletcontextlistener-example/)

Also the code will throw an NPE error since an instance of `Timer` is never created.

Comment: how can I add an instance of TestXMLSQLTimerLocal to the session?

Comment: Thanks for you answers but I don't understand very well the purpose of the ServletContextListener (I'm not an expert in JSP, just a little beginner)

Comment: @Jeremy.Vdb ServletContextListener executes when a J2EE application starts or is refreshed.  Stick with the session for now if your just learning.  Are you running into the issue where there the instance you created the timer with does not exist when you hit the stop button?

Comment: For now, the timer exists but it doesn't stopped when I hit the stop button. And no errors are shown. I think it's because when I press a button, the page is refreshed and it will create a new timer. So it cancels a timer but the wrong one. I don't know where I need to add `request.getSession().addAttribute("timer", new TestXMLSQLTimerLocal());`. I don't have any session running...

Comment: I found the solution, I will post it tomorrow because I don't have enough reputation. Thank you all

Answer (score 1):

Initiate the timer in your constructor not the start method:

```
public class TestXMLSQLTimerLocal
{
public Timer timer;    

public TestXMLSQLTimerLocal(){
   this.timer = new Timer();
}

public void start()
{
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask()
    {
        public void run()
        {
        //Some code
        }
    };

    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 60000);
}
public void stop() {
    this.timer.cancel();
}
}
```

Comment: You now have 2 constructors with zero arguments so this wont compile

Comment: upps. dont see that sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be sure that your start command is being called before the stop command. Also, put your `this.timer = new Timer();` into the constructor of your class.

Comment: I added it into the constructor. I haven't an null pointer exception but the timer is not cancelled. I'm sure the start method is called first because I'm only one who can pressed the button

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to cancel a different instance of the `timer` object from the one which started. You will need to debug this and inspect the object and see what is actually going on. Otherwise we are just guessing and it is very difficult to help you.

Comment: In my JSP page, if I press a button, the pages refreshes. I think the error is there, because if the page is refreshed, it will 'read' the code again that's right? But if I call an instance of my java class in the JSP code, did he 'read' the code or only if I called a method of this class?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, thanks to Kevin Bowersok

I split the Start and the Stop button in two pages, and I send via session my TestXMLSQLTimerLocal object.

To send the object via session :

```
session.putValue("TM",TM);
```

To get the value in the other page :

```
TestXMLSQLTimerLocal TM = (TestXMLSQLTimerLocal) session.getValue("TM");
```

Thanks for you help guys